# Is there a way to append rows to an existing Excel spreadsheet using the box/spout library?

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet

I tried to find some append method in the Writer class, but I found nothing.

Maybe is there a simple workaround, or should I just read the existing file and create a new one to append into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to directly append rows to a spreadsheet. You are right though, the solution is to read the entire spreadsheet and create a new one with the appended rows.

The reason for that is that Spout does not store an in-memory representation of the spreadsheet but works line by line.

You can find an example for this use case here: https://opensource.box.com/spout/guides/add-data-to-existing-spreadsheet/